# Select multiple rows by condition in R

Tags: r, select, intervals, tidyverse

I have the following extract of my dataset:

```
extract[989:993, ]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
   Dates                `Rating agency`
   <dttm>                <chr>
1 2014-07-11              NA
2 2014-07-14              NA
3 2014-07-15            DBRS
4 2014-07-16              NA
5 2014-07-17              NA
```

I would like to select the intervals [-1:1], which corresponds to the day before and the day after a downgrade. At the row where the column "Rating agency" is not "NA" indicates that a downgrade has occured. In my example above, rows [990:992].

My dataset has 45276 entries with 536 downgrades (column "Rating agency" is not "NA") where I would like to build a list containing the 3 rows where a downgrade is in between like this for my whole dataset:

```
extract[990:992, ]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   Dates          `Rating agency`
  <dttm>           <chr>
1 2014-07-14              NA
2 2014-07-15            DBRS
3 2014-07-16              NA
```

I tried it with this command:

```
interval1 <- basisanddowngradessingledates[`Rating agency` != "NA", c(-1:1), ]
```

Which resulted in this error:

```
Error in x[j] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
keepindex <- which(!is.na(basisanddowngradessingledates[,2]))
# keepindex <- which(basisanddowngradessingledates[,2] == "NA")  # try this if "NA" instead of NA
keepindex <- unique(c(keepindex-1, keepindex, keepindex+1))
basisanddowngradessingledates[keepindex,]
```

Comment: The second one worked but I had to change your  == "NA" to !=, since I want the downgrade dates and not the ones where no downgrade occured. Otherwise excellent, thanks a lot.

Comment: Good catch. Forgot you wanted the `!=`